# Serverless deployment not working (NestJs, AWS Lambda) - No verbose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless

I have setup the NestJs application for AWS Lambda deployment using serverless framework as suggested in the [Link](https://nishabe.medium.com/nestjs-serverless-lambda-aws-in-shortest-steps-e914300faed5)

When I do `sls offline start` it works fine.

But when I do `sls deploy -v`, it stuck. Refer screen shot below:

[image]

`serverless.yml` looks like:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, please read this:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4983752

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but I was stuck at the exact same place and in my case it was because the region I had put `eu-north-1` was not supported by the **Serverless Dashboard**. I saw the error message when I manually compiled the typescript and then deployed, without using `serverless-plugin-typescript`.